# how to check if integer which I want inside my value(if int is not iterable)

Tags: python, key, keyword-argument

I am trying to run this test code:

```
def test(**kwargs):
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        if 'sdk' in key:
            print value
            if 1 in value:
                print 'HelloWorld'    

test(sdk=1)
```

But of course it will give me error since integer is not iterable , so how do you guys check if integer which you want inside value? Thank you

Comment: How about `'1' in str(value)`?

Comment: @Vlad, see if the answer posted below helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression you actually should be using is `if value == 1`.

`if 1 in value` expects that `value` is an iterable (e.g., an array or a dict) and returns True if 1 is contained in `value`, and False otherwise.

If `value` is not an iterable, you'll get an exception:

```
>>> arr = [1, 2, 3]
>>> 1 in arr
True
>>> 4 in arr
False
>>> not_arr = 1
>>> 1 in not_arr
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
>>> not_arr == 1
True
>>> not_arr == 2
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `and` along with comparing the `'1'` with the `str` type of `value`:

```
def test(**kwargs):
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        if 'sdk' in key and '1' in str(value): # True in case of test(sdk=19)
                print('HelloWorld')

test(sdk=1)
```

**OR**

if you do not wish to cast the `1` into a `str` `'1'`,  `==` is what you could use:

```
if 'sdk' in key and 1 == value: # False in case of test(sdk=19)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
HelloWorld
```

Comment: @Aran-Fey that is what I did in an earlier edit, but then I thought of `test(sdk=19)` case.

Comment: @Aran-Fey `1 in [1,9]` to be specific?

Comment: @Aran-Fey okay, I just re-debugged, it wasn't doing that. Fixed, thank you!